# error when mounting nfs network-share in linux

Tags: linux, nfs, network-attached-storage, fstab

I'm trying to mount a nfs network share in various OSs (ubuntu 10.10/10.10 server/11.10) but continually get the same error:

```
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 128.251.xxx.xxx:/Systems
```

I have verified that I have `nfs-common` installed on my machine.  And my `/etc/fstab` mount command is as follows:

```
128.251.xxx.xxx:/Systems /home/me/uslonsnas001 nfs async,rw,hard,intr 0 0
```

The network device is a Seagate NAS, here are some screenshots of the device setup (through the web interface).

Verify that NFS is enabled for the share point named 'Systems'
[image]

Verify that NFS service is enabled on the device
[image]

Verify the share is set to enable public access:
[image]

**So what else could I be missing to make this mount work?**

Answer (score 4):

Generally there are permissions associated with NFS exports, i.e. hosts that are allowed to access NFS according to the server (in this case, your NAS).

A traditional export file that allows all hosts to access the export (aka share) looks as follows:

`/foo/bar *(ro,sync)`

`*` means all hosts, so you probably want to look for something similar in the GUI of your NAS

Comment: I understand - but since I cannot get into the CLI of the device how would I access this?  Plus, one (web-interface) config section I forgot to post says the volume is read/write enabled for public access.  I added another image to my OP to show this setting.

Comment: is there a way to nfs to a mount point by setting a username and password?

Comment: `showmount -e yournasiporhostname` will show the export list and options.  If it's not being exported to your client or there's a problem with the path it will turn up here.

Answer (score 2):

I just figured out my problem!

Found in this thread: http://forums.seagate.com/t5/BlackArmor-NAS-Network-Storage/Unable-to-nfs-mount-from-BlackArmor-440/td-p/28522

It seems that Seagate exports its NFS shares by first specifying the data-volume the share is found on (while when using CIFS, you can shorthand the path)

CIFS mount path:

```
 128.251.xxx.xxx:/Systems
```

NFS mount path:

```
 128.251.xxx.xxx:/DataVolume/Systems
```

such a simple stupid problem - very little documentation out there about it though - hope this helps someone else.